# Passing req.params around in Node MVC

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out how to pass req.params around using Express in the context of MVC.

I know how to properly reference req.params but when I split my app.js up into models and controllers I'm quite lost.

Code for reference:

routes.js

```
app.get('/category/:category', descriptor.getSingleCategory)
```

model.js

```
let getSingleCat = (cb) => {
    let queryString = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = $1'
    let queryValue = [req.params.category]
    db.query(queryString, queryValue, cb)
}
```

controller.js

```
const getSingleCategory = (req, response) => {
    console.log(req.params.category);
    db.desc.getSingleCat((err, queryRes) => {
        if (err) {
            //render something went wrong
            response.send('something went wrong')
        } else {
            response.send(queryRes.rows)
        }
    })
}
```

I've checked all requires and they are working correctly. Is there a vanilla way of passing req.params around without using middleware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to use the `req.params` in the model, is by sending it as parameters as the following example:

model.js

```
let getSingleCat = (params, cb) => {
    let queryString = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = $1'
    let queryValue = params.category
    db.query(queryString, queryValue, cb)
}
```

controller.js

```
const getSingleCategory = (req, response) => {
    console.log(req.params.category);
    db.desc.getSingleCat(req.params, (err, queryRes) => {
        if (err) {
            //render something went wrong
            response.send('something went wrong')
        } else {
            response.send(queryRes.rows)
        }
    })
}
```

You can't use global vars, so this is the only way to do it. Also, this variable (req) can only be accessed in the functions bound to an endpoint that will receive an actual request.

Comment: Trying to understand the flow correctly here, still new to MVC in node.

req from my routes.js will be passed to controller.js first which is stored in the argument req.params, which is then passed to model.js params?

Comment: Yes, that's right. First, your backend will receive a request, that will be binded by a route. That route will have a callback function associated, that receives two parameters (req, res). In this function, you will have access to all the request parameters, and its there where you will have the logic to handle them.